# Async Await es6 optimization

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, ecmascript-6, async-await, ecmascript-2017

I am trying to use async/await and my code works, I just need advice about is it the right way to use async/await, or do I need `.then`
 here. I have a function `loadDataForExport` - that return promise with generate data. Also, I have `actionButtons` with async event function, where I use asyn/await because in other case `let data = loadDataForExport()` - return promise.

```
loadDataForExport = async () => {
            const {sort, search} = this.state
            let dataForExport = await this.props.load({pageSize: this.props.totalCount, skip: 0, sort, search}).then(({entities: {devices, rooms}}) => Object.values(devices).map(({deviceType, deviceId, name, version, location, lastAliveMessage, deviceStatus}) => ({
                deviceType,
                deviceId,
                name,
                currentVersion: version,
                location: location && rooms[location] ? rooms[location].name : '',
                lastAliveMessage,
                deviceStatus,
            })))

            return dataForExport
        }


const actionButtons = loadDataForExport => [
    {
        event:  async () => {
            let data = await loadDataForExport()
            exportToExcel(data)
        },
        name: 'exportToExcel',,
    },
]
```

Comment: Yes, looks fine as for me.

Answer (score 3):

From my (too little) understanding of how async/await works, you are doing it the right way. I believe the following is true, feel free to correct me if i'm wrong (I'm ready to pay a few downvotes to get a better understanding of how it works) :

Await will wait (by the means of generators) for the given promise to be resolved before executing the next statement of the async function.

Thus, `let dataForExport = await this.props.load(...)` will assign the resolved value of `this.props.load(...)` to `dataForExport`.

Async function `loadDataForExport` will return a promise that will either resolve with the value of `dataForExport` or reject with the value of the rejected `this.props.load()`, which you can use with await just like you do in `loadDataForExport.event()`

Comment: Assign the resolved value of load is correct but the loadDataForExport function will immediately return a promise. If load causes an error or returns a rejected promise than the promise returned by getProresultByseriesFamily will reject as well.

Comment: @HMR right, thanks. Tried to edit my answer according to your comment